# A decorator function for batching computations for large data in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that does some computation. Computing it for each data point takes too long but computing it for the entire data set have memory and network problems. I **batch** my computations (say compute every 200 data points) to make things palatable.

Is there a way to decorate an arbitrary function given a batch size?

Something like:

```
@batchify(batch_size=200)
def long_computations(x):
    ...
    return x

data = [0]*100000
batched_results = long_computations(data)
```

I currently use a normal function which works but I think using decorators may be more modular.

```
def batchify(f, d, batch_size=200):
    assert isinstance(d, list), "data has to be in list form."
    N = len(d)
    results = []
    for i in xrange(N / batch_size + 1):
        low = i * batch_size
        high = min((i + 1) * batch_size, N)
        result = f(d[low:high])
        results.append(result)
    return [r for result in results for r in result]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to turn your current function into a decorator factory, just by adding a couple extra layers of nested functions:

```
import functools

def batchify(batch_size=200):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(d):
            assert isinstance(d, list), "data has to be in list form."
            N = len(d)
            results = []
            for i in xrange(N / batch_size + 1):
                low = i * batch_size
                high = min((i + 1) * batch_size, N)
                result = f(d[low:high])
                results.append(result)
            return [r for result in results for r in result]
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

I'd also suggest that you could simplify the batching logic a bit. Slicing a past the end of the list doesn't cause any problems. Python will treat a slice that goes past the end as if it went exactly to the end, which is exactly what we want. I'd use:

```
for i in xrange(0, N, batch_size):
    result = f(d[i:i + batch_size]) # This slice still works if i+batch_size > N
    ...
```

Comment: Another wrapper around the decorator. That makes sense thanks.